# How do you prevent a group from moving by itself when moving objects inside of it?

Tags: javafx, bluej

It seems that when I move the circle outside the group of squares, it moves the squares even though there is no code that does that. I'm 99% percent sure it is because the group is *trying to auto center itself*, but it only does it if I change the scale of the group. Here is the code that demonstrates the problem I'm currently having.*(Note that I don't want the square to move at all)*

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.util.Duration;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class Test extends Application
{
    private static Circle circle = new Circle(0, 0, 10);
    private static Group group = new Group(circle);
    private static Group mainPane = new Group(group);
    private Scene scene = new Scene(mainPane, 600, 600);
    public void start(Stage stage){
        circle.setViewOrder(-1);
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
            Rectangle backGround = new Rectangle(-10, -10, 20, 20);
            backGround.setLayoutX((i - (int)(i * .1) * 10) * 20 - 100);
            backGround.setLayoutY((int)(i * .1) * 20 - 100);
            group.getChildren().add(backGround);
        }
        
        /*This line causes the problem*/group.setScaleX(1.5);
        /*This line causes the problem*/group.setScaleY(1.5);
        group.setLayoutX(200);
        group.setLayoutY(200);
        circle.setFill(Color.RED);
        Timeline time = new Timeline();
        time.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        KeyFrame frame = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1), new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
            @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e){
                circle.setLayoutX(circle.getLayoutX() + .1);
                if(circle.getLayoutX() > 150) circle.setLayoutX(0);                
            }
        });
        time.getKeyFrames().add(frame);
        time.playFromStart();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So I believe the problem is that `scaleX` / `scaleY` uses the center of the node as the pivot point. Combine that with the fact that the `Group` grows as the `Circle` moves to the right, and the scaling causes the `Group` to "move" because the *new* center becomes the pivot point.

When I replace:

> ```java
> /*This line causes the problem*/group.setScaleX(1.5);
> /*This line causes the problem*/group.setScaleY(1.5);
> ```

With:

```java
// javafx.scene.transform.Scale
Scale scale = new Scale(1.5, 1.5);
group.getTransforms().add(scale);
```

Your problem goes away. Unlike with `scaleX` / `scaleY`, the pivot point used by `Scale` is not automatically adjusted as the `Group` grows. Note the above `Scale` is using `(0,0)` as the pivot point. I assume that's okay, but if you want then you can set the pivot point to the initial center point of the `Group` (just don't constantly update the pivot point, or you'll probably run into the same problem as before).